# Error when trying to implement 'Math' library

Tags: ruby, sublimetext3

Sublime Text 3 throws an error  "in `require': cannot load such file -- Math" when im trying to use Math.sqrt(x) method.

```
    /usr/lib/ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in 
`require': cannot load such file -- Math (LoadError)
    from /usr/lib/ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in 
`require'
    from /home/damian/Pulpit/tibia.rb:1:in `<main>'
```

and my code:

```
require 'Math'

def square_digits(num)
num = num.to_s.each_char.map(&:to_i).Math.sqrt(num)**2
return num

end

puts square_digits(91)
```

any advices how to fix this? i can't continue without this

Comment: You don't need to require it.  The module is part of core: http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.1/Math.html.

Comment: then it throws this error: in     `square_digits': undefined method Math' for [9, 1]:Array`

Comment: i just can't use it after a dot, right?:D that was an issue

Comment: @joedoe yep. Dot is a method call. Class - is not a method :)

Comment: `::` is a scope resolution operator.

Answer (score 0):

You use Math like this:

```
Math::sqrt(99)
=> 9.9498743710662
```

or

```
numbers = [0, 64, 273]
numbers.map{|num| Math.sqrt(num)}
=> [0.0, 8.0, 16.522711641858304]
```

In your case `Math.sqrt(num.to_i)**2` *(or `.to_f`)* should suffice.